# Retrieving camera intent image full image uri

Tags: android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I've found ways that have supposedly worked for people to retrieve the uri/bitmap of the camera taken image.
But when I try and create a bitmap out of the non-null uri that I'm getting the file isn't created and doesn't exist.

this the the function which I use to open the camera intent(Which is copied from stackoverflow):

```
private void openBackCamera() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    currentImageBase64 = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
    File file = new File(currentImageBase64);
    Log.d("2","file 1: " +file.exists());
    Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"com.mydomain.fileprovider",file);
    currentImageBase64 =outputFileUri+"";
    Log.d("2",outputFileUri+" is the uri got from camera");
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

and this is how I handel my images:

```
            Log.d("2","camera request!"+ currentImageBase64);
            File imgFile = new  File(currentImageBase64);
            if(imgFile.exists()) {
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

                ivPreview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }else{
                Log.d("2","file does not exist");
            }
```

note that the camera request log shows that currentImagesBase64 is not null and has a value "content://com.mydomain.fileprovider/name/Pictures/20190121_173332.jpg"
the file anyway, does not exist.

/**
edit: the problem was insufficent permissions, camera and read&write permissions were requested and the problem was resolved!
**/

Comment: Delete `currentImageBase64 =outputFileUri+"";`.

Comment: @CommonsWare didnt work :(, camera request Log "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20190121_181750.jpg" and the file exists check failed.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions, including runtime permissions? Did you check whether the file is there using Android Studio's Device File Explorer?

Comment: Why are not you getting the bitmap from Intent you get in onActivityResult method?

Comment: Have you added FileProvider in your manifest file?

Comment: Turn out Permissions were the problem, once I gave runtime camera read&write storage permissions the problem was fixed!

Comment: That's cool you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out Permissions were the problem, once I gave runtime camera read&write storage permissions the problem was fixed!